# Calling object names in a flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

Excuse me if the title is misleading.

What I want is when updating, creating or deleting an object (for example, a **product**), the flash message contains the product title.

I tried this code:

```
redirect_to products_path, notice: "The product - #{product.title} - was deleted!"
```

but it gave an undefined local variable or method error.

What are the ways to do this?

Comment: You are doing it the right way, but perhaps `product` does not exist in the current scope.  Or maybe you mean `@product`?

Comment: @infused Oh, right! I needed to make it an instance! Thanks for the advice! Cheers! :)